# Non-constant, odd and entire is surjective

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

If $f$ is a non-constant, entire analytic function, which is odd, then it is also surjective, due to Picard's Little Theorem. Clearly, $f(0)=0$, and hence $0$ is not missed, and if $f(z)\ne a$, for all $z$, then $f(z)\ne-a$, for all $z$. So if $f$ is not onto, it misses at least two values, and Picard's Little Theorem implies that $f$ is constant.

Is it possible to show this without Picard's Little Theorem?

*Otherwise,* Is it possible to derive Picard's Little Theorem from this *odd* version of Picard's Little Theorem?

Comment: How do you prove it *with* Picard's little Theorem?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have explained it in my modified question.

Comment: Did you mean to say if $f(z) \ne a$ for any $z$ then $f(z) \color{red}{\ne} -a$ for any $z$?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis I should have guessed it myself. Thanks.

Comment: @tilper Of course. I've edited the question.

Comment: I didn't find an obvious way to obtain the Picard's little theorem from the Picard's little theorem for odd functions. 
If $g$ is entire, the odd Picard little theorem implies for every $a \in \mathbb{C}^*$ and every odd non-zero entire function $h$ there exists $b = B(a,h)$ such that $h(b) g(b^2) = a$

Comment: The little Picard theorem says [that $\lambda$ is holomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lambda_function#Little_Picard_theorem) surjective $\mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0,1\}$. If $f$ is entire and avoids $0,1$ then $\lambda^{-1}(f(z))$ is entire $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{H}$ and $\frac{1}{\lambda^{-1}(f(z))+i}$ is entire and bounded and hence constant. To prove the odd little Picard theorem, you'll replace $\lambda$ by an holomorphic surjective function $\mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{C} \setminus \{-1,0,1\}$